# What does these mean in SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG in django-summernote?

Tags: django, summernote

## settings.py

SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {

```
'attachment_upload_to': my_custom_upload_to_func(),

'attachment_storage_class': 'my.custom.storage.class.name',

'attachment_model': 'my.custom.attachment.model',
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as you know `django-summernote` is a rich text editor field used in django.
but when you implement that plugin to your app you get only minimum features and default options. when you add `SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG` you can customize your rich text field and add more features in it.

for example:

In your question you add some keys and values in 'SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG' it is about adding attachments. `attachment_upload_to` is path to the folder which needs to save attachments. `attachment_model` is to create a model for your attachments

eg:

```
# my/custom/attachment.py

from django_summernote import AbstractAttachment

class Attachment(django_summernote.AbstractAttachment):
    pass


# django_project/settings.py
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {

    'attachment_upload_to': '/path/to/attachment_folder',
    'attachment_model': 'my.custom.attachment.Attachment',
}
```

Comment: If attachment_upload_to is the path to a folder, then why does it mention as "my_custom_upload_tu_function()"

Comment: 'attachment_upload_to': '/path/to/attachment_folder',

Comment: oh ya okay, and can you please tell me what this is..'attachment_storage_class': 'my.custom.storage.class.name'?

Comment: hey storage class is a file handler it manage save, delete, overwrite etc. but its not so important because django already have s default file storage class it will handle managing part for us. if you need any extra managing features you need to overwrite file storage by inherit from `from django.core.files.storage import Storage`